# Weird behavior when multiple click events are bound - Binding to selector VS Event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

I was testing a scenario where in I need have 2 click events on a selector (As an example 2 links).

I believe the events are bound to the element top down order where the event has been initialized.

**Generic case**

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("Click me !!!");
});


$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log("Click me again clicked!!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#">Click me</a>

<a href="#">Click me again </a>
```

As expected I see the following 2 lines in the console as expected in the right order.

```
Click me !!!
Click me again clicked!!!
```

But when I delegated the first event to the body and performed the same action the order is reversed, which is what I did not expect.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log("Click me !!!");
});


$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log("Click me again clicked!!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click me</a>

<a href="#">Click me again </a>
```

```
Click me again clicked!!!
Click me !!!
```

I was puzzled as why this was happening as I expected the events to be fired in the order which they were bound to.

The reason I wanted to do this, in one scenario I would like to prevent the 2nd event from firing when the delegated event is present.

I also tried using `e.stopPropagation` , thinking the event will stop bubbling and can stop the 2nd event from firing. But it would not help as the 2nd event seems to be firing first.

Any thought would be appreciated as I am trying to figure out why that is happening.

Comment: The snippets you provided are expected behaviors, 1st Snippet - jquery bounds both the events and not replaces the events. You can use namespaces like 'click.myNamespace' to remove the event manually. 2nd Snippet - the event is bubbling up the DOM tree. When you put e.stopPropagation in 2nd code snippets 2nd event (without delegate) the event on body is not getting triggered as the bubbling is stopped at a tag itself and that is expected. If you have access to the code for both events and the controls - you can try using eventTarget to work around your particular scenario

Comment: @SimranjitSingh Right. I could use the `e.target` to check for the element and write conditional logic to execute a piece of code. What if I have 50 anchor elements on my page and each of them have a click event associated in a different view. It would be a pain to go to all the places and replace the logic using event delegation and moving into 1 event with 50 conditionals to handle the scenarios.

Comment: I dont think its supposed to work in that way, If you get a solution other than using a conditional statement - please post it here for the community. Try looking at your code from some levels above than your current outlook, you might be able to do things in another way and you might not require such odd scenario to handle. Goodluck